# Add user input to array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am trying to add user input to a previously created array with array_merge.  However, I am having trouble echoing the entire, new array as an unordered list.  the user's entry is being processed correctly, but the original array is displaying as "Array" within the unordered list.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$travel = array("Automobile", "Jet", "Ferry", "Subway");

foreach ($travel as $t)
    {
    echo "<ul>";

    echo "<li>$t</li>";

    echo "</ul>";

    }
?>

<form action="arrays.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="added" />
<?php

foreach ($travel as $t)
{
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"travel[]\" value=\"$t\" />";      
}

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add More!" />
</form>

<?php

$travel = array($_POST["travel"]);

$added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);

$travel = array_merge($travel, $added);

echo "<p> Here is the list with your additions:</p>";

echo "<ul>";

foreach ($travel as $t)
{
echo "<li>$t</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: This has been solved by removing "array()" from the first $travel variable and preceding it with if (isset($_POST["submit"])).

I will post the code as an answer...thanks for the feedback everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a new variable name for the new array created by array_merge(). I think you may run into problems modifying the array you're storing into.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck with that approach...any other ideas?

Comment: OH, I think you just need to change 
$travel = array($_POST["travel"]);
to $travel = $_POST["travel"]; (in addition to using a new variable name). $_POST["travel"] is already an array.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing. This works for me (tested):           $travel = $_POST["travel"];        

$added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);         

$ntravel = array_merge($travel, $added);        

print_r( $ntravel );

Comment: I just copied and pasted your input...same warning...maybe warnings are turned off???

Answer (score 0):

```
$travel = array($_POST["travel"]);
```

should be

```
$travel = $_POST['travel'];
```

Comment: \"travel\" without [] will print only the last value of the array.

Comment: Sorry i've been misslead by $added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);
 what are you trying to do there ? Because explode takes a string as a second argument and $_post['added'] is an array

Comment: The user can add items to the first array by entering options, comma separated.  Once submit is clicked, the old array plus the user's input should display as one, unordered list...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved thus:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$travel = $_POST["travel"];
$added = explode(",", $_POST["added"]);
$travel = array_merge($travel, $added);


echo "<p> Here is the list with your additions:</p>";

echo "<ul>";

foreach ($travel as $t)
    {
    echo "<li>$t</li>";
    }

echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```